# Unable to call method of ViewController()

Tags: ios, swift

I am simply trying to make a method in the ViewController class and be able to call it.

Here is my code (I note the 2 ways I tried calling it, and the errors I got):

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController{
    func sayHi(name: String){
        print("Hi \(name)")
    }
}

/*
let viewcontroller = ViewController()
viewcontroller.sayHi(name: "Bob")
*/

//Error: Expressions are not allowed at the top level

/*
ViewController.sayHi(name: "Bob")
*/

//Error: Expressions are not allowed at the top level
//Error: Instance member 'sayHi' cannot be used on type 'ViewController'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead?
```

So as you can see in the commenting, I tried to call sayHi as a type method and as an instance method. Neither worked. I will ultimately create a function that can take input from a text input, and manipulate it. Is ViewController.swift even the right file to be doing this? If so, how do I call a method that I have defined?

Comment: What are you trying to do here exactly? Do you want the viewController to load when the app starts? Then you should be doing it in appDelegate and setting the rootViewController of the window to the instance you created.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri yeah, and right now at least, I want the method to run immediately as well. Later on, I can add complexity, but my main issue is how to call the sayHi method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will be this delegate in `appDelegate` which will be called when you app is launched. Create your `viewController` there and add it to the **window**.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    let viewController = ViewController()
    window?.rootViewController = viewController
    viewController.sayHi()
    return true
}
```

Comment: Thanks! So what if, for instance, I have a `@IBAction', and I want sayHi() to be called when that action is triggered. Where would I do that?

Comment: @Addison That method would be called when your button is clicked, if your IBAction is hooked to the code and this would be inside your ViewController. Your button clicking would be the trigger.

Comment: Will do! I tried before, but SO as a weird rule where you have to do it 5 min after the answer is given

Answer (score 0):

This will work on Playground, but not on Xcode.

Xcode's code is compiled and then you have an app. The first point where a call happens is AppDelegate and from there your first controller and its methods are initialised. Nothing outside a class will be executed.

Use playground for tests or any other online swift playground.

If you want to run `sayHi` immediately, put it in `viewDidLoad` and load the app. Delete all further code outside of the class before building again:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    sayHi()
}
```

Comment: oh I see! So how would I do it at a time other than when the app first launches? Should that be in the AppDelegate.swift file?

Comment: Ideally the AppDelegate launches your first viewController and then the viewController takes it from there. Methods that want to be called right on start should be called in `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear`.

Answer (score 0):

> You can create a instance of controller inside a function or a block
>   when you are working in a `class` or Xcode projects in Xcode Playground your way of accessing the function `sayHi(name: String)` in
>   ViewController works.

For Xcode projects try the following

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController{
    func sayHi(name: String){
        print("Hi \(name)")
    }
}

class SecondViewController: UIViewController{
    override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      let viewcontroller = ViewController()
      viewcontroller.sayHi(name: "Bob")
    }
}
```

When you initialise the SecondViewController you can access the  ViewController()

> To execute the function sayHi(name: String) immediately  when the
>   ViewController() is initialised you can call it in viewDidLoad() or in
>   func viewWillAppear()

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController{

override func viewDidLoad(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidLoad(animated)
 //Call the function hear 
  sayHi(name: "Bob")

}
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
   // or call hear
   sayHi(name: "Bob")
}

func sayHi(name: String){
        print("Hi \(name)")
    }
}
```